# Send HTML email from google spreadsheet using a button

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am new to stack overflow and am looking for some advice and some guidance on a google spreadsheet i have been working on.

A demo of it can be found at

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1t9WfcG_1_mAavpN0l3v58JdD04Y1lL3PhAEoTUkq0Z4/edit?usp=sharing

Basically the jist of it is that i require the following.

A sendEmail button in the tool bar at the top that will send a html formatted email to any email on the active page in a specific colour.

Essentially this is to allow me to send reminder to clients in groups and by colour status. Currently i have to mail each client individually using a canned response which is pretty time consuming.

So far i am using the following script as a basis, i can successfully send an email but i run into errors if email fields are empty. I am looking for it to overlook the empty fields and continue searching for an email address. Also i can only get it to locate a template of an active sheet but would require it to locate a template of another sheet and use that. Finally when i try adding in HTML the script successfully picks up the template but sends it as plain text and its not sent as HTML.

```
function sendEmails() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var startRow = 2;  // First row of data to process
  var numRows = 100;   // Number of rows to process
  // Fetch the range of cells A2:B3
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, 100)
  // Fetch values for each row in the Range.
  var data = dataRange.getValues();
  for (i in data) {
    var row = data[i];
    var emailAddress = row[8];  // Eight column
    var message = row[15];       // Fifteenth column
    var subject = "Welcome To Phorest";
    MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);
  }
}
```

Looking forward to speaking with someone that can help me work all this out and save me some data entry in the process.

Appreciated.

Comment: There is no way to add a button to the toolbar.  You can add a custom menu, or an Add-on menu.  You can add an image inside of the spreadsheet, with a script assigned to it.  When the image is clicked, the script will run.

Comment: show us your attempts for each requirement. the code shown is not attempting any.

Answer (score 2):

You can send an HTML-containing email the following way:

```
var email = "some@email.com";
var subject = "Hello!";
var html = '<p> What is your favourite fruit? </p> <br>' +
           '<select>' +
           '<option value="apple">Apple</option>' +
           '<option value="orange">Orange</option>' +
           '</select> ';
MailApp.sendEmail({
      to: email,
      subject: subject,
      htmlBody: html
      });
```